# Flurry banner with error code 3

Tags: android, admob, flurry

I'm trying to use AdMob with Flurry mediation network.
I've tried several times since 2016 but still had no luck.
This time it returns error code 3 when it do the ad request.
Which means "No context - A valid context is missing".
But the native ads works well with MoPub SDK(Because native ad view of AdMob SDK has a terrible performance on scrolling).

There are two different error messages:

Listener cannot be null.(Disappears after the second request)

```
V/FlurryAdapter: Requesting Banner Ad
V/FlurryAdapter: Banner view is created for {width = 840px, height = 131px}
E/FlurryAgent: Listener cannot be null
```

Error code 3.

```
V/FlurryAdapter: Requesting Banner Ad
V/FlurryAdapter: Banner view is created for {width = 840px, height = 131px}
D/a: onError(com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdBanner@1ef147fFETCH20)
V/FlurryAdapter: Calling onFailedToReceiveAd for Banner with errorCode: 3
V/FlurryAdapter: Destroy Ad
```

Answer (score 2):

This error: "FlurryAdapter: Calling onFailedToReceiveAd for Banner with errorCode: 3" is slightly misleading, as it does not match directly to the listed error codes, which are for non-adapter integrations. The relevant line from your log is the one before it, "onError(com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdBanner@1ef147fFETCH20)", which says that the error is a fetch error code 20, indicating a lack of fill for your geographic area. Without seeing the full code, it is likely that the error is strictly due to lack of fill.

Comment: But when I change to use Native ads, the fill rate is nearly 100%. And I've seen another app displayed banner ads of Flurry. How come my app can't show them?

Comment: What version of the Flurry SDK are you using?

Comment: `com.flurry.android:ads:10.1.0@aar`

Comment: Native ads usually have much higher fill rates than banner ads. Can you paste your banner integration code? And is it in the context of an Activity?

Comment: According to the AdMob document, there's no need to write any code to integrate mediation networks. What kind of code do you need? gradle? And yes, I pass an Activity as a context. Otherwise you should see a error message about wrong context problem.